# Can a Solid Bone-Like bone "extension" be used?

Tags: bones

I've always wondered if instead of the silicon-based implants for some parts of the body, particularly the chin, could be substituted with a solid piece of material, maybe plastic or even titanium or harder metals, to create sort of a bone extension. I've no actual example of this exact idea working, but there are quite similar cases.

What I mean by Bone-extension, is that it would be used on people with functional bones but underdeveloped ones, such as missing-chin, weak bones and things like that, and would not serve the functionality of a prosthesis, as the prosthesis replaces the missing bones, while these "implants" would only add up to the bone preexisting structure.
That would be something 3D printed based on the needs of the patient.

For example, this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrASOLP4Fg8
in which surgeons created the *missing* bone due to HMF, or `Hemifacial Microsomia` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemifacial_microsomia) which leads to an underdeveloped part of the mandible (If I understand correctly). And to solve that, a titanium prosthesis was created to fit exactly the needs of the patient.

What I'm talking about is quite similar to the one shown in the video, but the purpose as stated below is not to replace a bone, but to enhance a pre-existing one. The material could be titanium like in the video or a more elastic one that wouldn't create many problems in case of a fall, for example (in which case it would absorb part of the impact and not deliver it completely on the fragile bone above) or in the case the "prosthesis" is fixed during a time in which the patient can grow.

To better explain what I mean I created this drawing, sorry if it's a bit creepy and unprofessional but I do not have a graphics tablet to draw on, so I had to adapt :'). I hope it is clear what is the purpose. If it doesn't or it's too ugly, comment it and I'll try to make a better one.
[image: bad self-made image to better explain the concept.]

As you can see, the Red silhouette represents sort of a "weak chin". (to be clear and honest, I don't exactly know if it is exactly the skull-level cause of the weak chin. And I'm not completely sure it's the right term for it.) and the Blue one should represent an underdeveloped mandible. I tried googling weak chin skull but found no representation so I tried guessing it by the exterior appearance. As you can see (or at least I hope) the black part represents the "prosthesis", which would have the shape of the 3D labeled draw (sorry again for the ugliness), so quite like a denture? (sorta).

Anyway, I couldn't find much more from trustable and reliable sources, but it's to say that English isn't my main language, so maybe I'm not using the right word. I tried searching for "3D printed chin implant" as 3D printing is the technique I think would be the best to use. Or I also tried with "titanium chin implant" but I found not that big of an amount of articles or sources.

So, does anyone know if it's actually possible, and if it is, has it already been done or is it currently available?

If there is something unclear in my explainings, feel free to comment and I'll edit the question to fix it! Thanks for reading!

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Please visit our site [tour].  You said *"I've read that it has already been done on cancer patient for functional purposes and one some "normal" people for aesthetic purposes, but I'm not 100% sure I could trust the source."* What is the source you talk about?  For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the sources were too shabby, because were on sites that promoted different things  from what they stated in the title of the articles. sort of clickbait style. that's why I didn't link them. It was more like a justification for where the idea come from more than a source to prove it's possible. anyway, I'm explaining it better in the question.

Comment: That's fair enough @Fabrizio as I would not like to encourage clickbait links myself.  But we still need prior research information.  Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.  I am not the person who downvoted your question but it could be for this reason, as stated in my previous comment. (Please see the reasons and how to ask links).

Comment: I've added more explanations and a source, I hope is more clear now,  I'm still searching for better ones, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: That is better.  +1